# MYSQL: write insert query based on first column value repeated in second column

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have following table and I would like to compose 'insert' query to find how many connections are there for mod.

```
id  mod     modele  
90  act     gend    
22  act     gend    
54  act     ent     
53  act     ent     
95  act     genext
61  act     ent
```

I want to write a query to insert the above in below format

```
id  Mod     ConnMod     noConn
1   act     gend        2
2   act     ent         3
3   act     genext      1
```

Please help me.

Comment: You need to rephrase your question. Your expectation is not clear at all...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT @i:=0;
```

and then

```
INSERT INTO [table_name](column_names1, column_name2...)
SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS id,
       Mod,
       modele as ConnMod,
       count(*) as noConn
From Table
Group By Mod, modele
```

[EDIT] added the initialization of @i.

Comment: You haven't set @i to an initial value so it's doing nothing here except returning NULL for each row. This is fine if id is Primary Key and auto_increment but otherwise errors. If id is PK,AI then you can leave @i out entirely.

Comment: Except @i issue, rest the query is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: oops, thanks for acknowledging. was afk for a while, will make that edit.